# Dynamic creation of views inside relative layout stacked

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-relativelayout

So I've got a relative layout that contains other relative layouts. The child layouts contain various information that I'm parsing from a JSON object(which has key/values as well as child JSON arrays with child key/val objects). The user navigates to each root JSON object through a list fragment which brings up the details fragment. The root detail info, (name, image, description, and so on) displays great.

Hierarchy:

Committee:

- Name
- Image
- Description
- Members: JSON Array of Objects

Member:
- Name
- State
- Image

Here's the layout file:

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frmCommitteeDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <!-- Logo and Title Container -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frmImage_Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">"

        <!-- Committee Logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCommitteeLogo"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_comm"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:padding="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCommitteeName"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgCommitteeLogo"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgCommitteeLogo"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Description -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frmComDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/frmImage_Title"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <!-- Webview to have proper text layout -->
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/txtComDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Contact Infomation -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frmComContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/frmComDescription"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <!-- Contact Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComContactTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/contact_info"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <!-- Separator -->
        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:id="@+id/imgLineComContactTitle"
            android:src="@drawable/cell_divider_line"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtComContactTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <!-- URL -->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txtComContactURL"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imgLineComContactTitle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="www.gooogle.com/url/url/link"/>
        <!-- Email -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComContactEmail"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtComContactURL"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="comemail@comsemail.com"/>
        <!-- Name -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComContactName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtComContactEmail"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="John McGee, Contact Guy"/>
        <!-- Number -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComContactNumber"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtComContactName"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="(888)-777-1234"/>
        <!-- Address -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComContactAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtComContactNumber"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="08 War Memorial Bldg"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Members -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frmComMemberList"
        android:layout_below="@id/frmComContact"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners">

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</code>
```

Here's the fragment as it is right now:

```
<code>
package v4dev.android.general_assembly.fragment;

import v4dev.android.general_assembly.R;
import v4dev.android.general_assembly.model.CommitteeModel;
import v4dev.android.general_assembly.model.CommitteeModel.Member;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class CommitteeDetailFragment extends Fragment
{
    private CommitteeModel Committee = new CommitteeModel();

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public CommitteeDetailFragment(CommitteeModel committee)
    {
        this.Committee = committee; 
    }

    // Create View
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(v4dev.android.general_assembly.R.layout.com_detail, container, false);

        ImageView imgLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgCommitteeLogo);
        TextView txtCommitteeName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCommitteeName);

        imgLogo.setImageResource(this.Committee.imageID);
        txtCommitteeName.setText(this.Committee.name);

        createDescription(view);
        createContactInfo(view);
        createMembers(view, container);
        return view;
    }// End onCreateView

    // Description
    public void createDescription(View view)
    {   
        // Using a web view since its near impossible to get justified indented text with a native TextView
        // Text View
        WebView txtComDescription       = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComDescription);

        // Fill or collapse
        if(!(this.Committee.description.length()==0))
        {
            String Description = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\" style=\"text-indent: 25px\">";
            Description += this.Committee.description;
            Description += "</p></body></html>";
            //txtComDescription.setText(this.Committee.description);
            txtComDescription.loadData(Description,"text/html", "utf-8");
        }
        else
        {
            txtComDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    // Contact Info
    public void createContactInfo(View view)
    {   
        // Text Views
        TextView txtComContactURL       = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComContactURL);
        TextView txtComContactEmail     = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComContactEmail);
        TextView txtComContactName      = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComContactName);
        TextView txtComContactNumber    = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComContactNumber);
        TextView txtComContactAddress   = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtComContactAddress);

        // Fill Data into Layout
        // Collapse Layout if not existent 

        // url
        if(!(this.Committee.url.length() == 0))
        {
            txtComContactURL.setText(this.Committee.url);
        }
        else
        {
            txtComContactURL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // contact_email
        if(!(this.Committee.contact_email.length() == 0))
        {
            txtComContactEmail.setText(this.Committee.contact_email);
        }
        else
        {
            txtComContactEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // contact_name
        if(!(this.Committee.contact_name.length() == 0))
        {
            txtComContactName.setText(this.Committee.contact_name);
        }
        else
        {
            txtComContactName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // contact_number
        if(!(this.Committee.contact_number.length() == 0))
        {
            txtComContactNumber.setText(this.Committee.contact_number);
        }
        else
        {
            txtComContactNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // contact_address
        if(!(this.Committee.contact_address.length() == 0))
        {
            txtComContactAddress.setText(this.Committee.contact_address);
        }
        else
        {
            txtComContactAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }// end CreateContactInfo()

    // Display all Committee Members
    public void createMembers(View view, ViewGroup container)
    {
        RelativeLayout frmComMemberList = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frmComMemberList);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int id = 1;
        for(Member member: this.Committee.MemberList)
        {

            ImageView imgMember = new ImageView(container.getContext());
            imgMember.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imgMember.setMaxHeight(60);
            imgMember.setMaxWidth(60);
            imgMember.setId(id);
            imgMember.setImageResource(member.imageID);
            imgMember.setLayoutParams(lp);

            if(id > 1)
            {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imgMember.getId()  );
                frmComMemberList.addView(imgMember,lp);
            }
            else
            {
                frmComMemberList.addView(imgMember);
            }
            id++;


        }// EndFor
    }
}

</code>
```

I'm trying to "stack" the members on top of each other dynamically using the relative layout params. The problem with that is the id of the new views created in the fragment are generated at runtime. Is it possible to "stack" them as if they were a list view, or am I better of going another route by using an actual listview/adapter combo, or even dare I say... a tableview?

Thanks in advance SO peeps! :)

Comment: UPDATE: Since then I have fixed the problem, just had to wrap each view inside a table row and it worked from there.